# fitEllipse returns ellipses that is twice as big as the actual contour

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, contour

[image]

As you can see the contour is much smaller than the fitted ellipse. Below is the relevant code I use to generate the ellipse. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

```
cv2.drawContours(orig, contour,-1, (0, 255, 0),3) #draw the green contour on image "orig"
(center, size, angle) = cv2.fitEllipse(contour) #get best fit Ellipse from contour
cv2.ellipse(grey_scale,(int(round(center[0])),int(round(center[1]))),(int(round(size[0])),int(round(size[1]))),int(round(angle)),0,360,(0,255,0),1) # draw ellipse on image "grey_scale" with the statistics gathered from second line
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [draw function](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#ellipse) expects half of the size:

> **axes** – Half of the size of the ellipse main axes.

A simpler way of doing this is:

```
cv2.drawContours(orig, contour,-1, (0,255,0), 3)
my_ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(contour)
cv2.ellipse(grey_scale, my_ellipse, (0,255,0), 1)
```